# Python merge list concating unique values as comma seperated

Tags: python

I am trying to get this to work.

Here is my data:

data.csv

```
id,fname,lname,education,gradyear,attributes
1,john,smith,mit,2003,qa
1,john,smith,harvard,207,admin
1,john,smith,ft,212,master
2,john,doe,htw,2000,dev
```

Trying to use this code. Found this code on the Internet, don't fully understand it.

```
from itertools import groupby
import csv
import pprint


t = csv.reader(open('data.csv'))
t = list(t)


def join_rows(rows):
    def join_tuple(tup):
        for x in tup:
            if x: 
                return x
        else:
            return x
    return [join_tuple(x) for x in zip(*rows)]



for name, rows in groupby(sorted(t), lambda x:x[0]):
    print join_rows(rows)
```

However, it does not merge unique values as comma separated.

The output is:

```
['1', 'john', 'smith', 'ft', '212', 'master']
['2', 'john', 'doe', 'htw', '2000', 'dev']
['id', 'fname', 'lname', 'education', 'gradyear', 'attributes']
```

How can I make it like:

```
['1', 'john', 'smith', 'mit,harvard,ft', '2003,207,212', 'qa,admin,master']
['2', 'john', 'doe', 'htw', '2000', 'dev']
['id', 'fname', 'lname', 'education', 'gradyear', 'attributes']
```

If there are more entries for the same column, it should also work. Should not be limited to 3 rows.

Grrrrr .... anybody have tips or ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"Trying to use this code. Found this code on the Internet, don't fully understand it."* That's not really a good way to learn going forward.

Comment: a code snippet is only as good as how well you understand its use

Comment: Should this code put all of john smith's items in the same row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the definition of `join_rows` to

```
import itertools

def join_rows(rows):
    return [(e[0] if i < 3 else ','.join(e)) for (i, e) in enumerate(zip(*rows))]
```

What this does is to zip all entries belonging to the same id into tuples. For the first 3 tuples, the first item is returned; for the latter, they are joined by commas.

```
['1', 'john', 'smith', 'ft,harvard,mit', '212,207,2003', 'master,admin,qa']
['2', 'john', 'doe', 'htw', '2000', 'dev']
['id', 'fname', 'lname', 'education', 'gradyear', 'attributes']
```

Comment: Looks great!!!! Thanks!!! I will try to figure it out on my own, unless it's easy and you know it. Is there a way to make the values appear as they are in csv i.e not "ft,harvard,mit" but "mit,harvard,ft", this also applies to other fields ... in the output this seems to be reversed

Comment: @android_dev It's a bit more complicated (not by much). You need to sort it by the id for the `groupby` to work, but retain the original indices for what you're asking. I suggest you try to work on it a bit on your own. If it doesn't work out for you, could you open a separate question? If you drop here a link, I'll be happy to take a look at it there.

Comment: Naaaahhhh .... I would just try to reverse the order on that field. Could not follow on your tip. Here is the link to new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505658/python-merge-list-concating-unique-values-as-comma-seperated-retaining-original When you have time, if would be great if you can explain it step by step. Thanks in advance and for helping beginners trying to solve problems!!!