# Merge list concating unique values as comma seperated retaining original order from csv

Tags: python

Here is my data:

data.csv

```
id,fname,lname,education,gradyear,attributes
1,john,smith,mit,2003,qa
1,john,smith,harvard,207,admin
1,john,smith,ft,212,master
2,john,doe,htw,2000,dev
```

Here is the code:

```
from itertools import groupby
import csv
import pprint


t = csv.reader(open('data.csv'))
t = list(t)


def join_rows(rows):
    return [(e[0] if i < 3 else ','.join(e)) for (i, e) in enumerate(zip(*rows))]



for name, rows in groupby(sorted(t), lambda x:x[0]):
    print join_rows(rows)
```

It works, but while merging it doest not retain original order, instead it works from concating last to first

Output is:

```
['1', 'john', 'smith', 'ft,harvard,mit', '212,207,2003', 'master,admin,qa']
['2', 'john', 'doe', 'htw', '2000', 'dev']
['id', 'fname', 'lname', 'education', 'gradyear', 'attributes']
```

Instead of:

```
['1', 'john', 'smith', 'mit,harvard,ft', '2003,207,212', 'qa,admin,master']
['2', 'john', 'doe', 'htw', '2000', 'dev']
['id', 'fname', 'lname', 'education', 'gradyear', 'attributes']
```

as it is listed in the CSV file (original order)

My approach to fix this would be to rerun though values and try to reverse it. Is there any cleverer approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is sorting, which is not required. Change as:

```
groupby(t, lambda x:x[0])
```